# How to add php old code in php blade view

Tags: php, laravel

I started a laravel + vuejs project (fontend and backend in the same project).
It is basically a migration from a pure php-html project. I am wondering if it would be possible to migrate only a part of it, and to integrate the rest of it.
After your answers (thanks :) ), here is myview.blade.php:

```
@extends('template')

@section('contenu')
<div id="app">
    @php
       $path = public_path('myview/oldfile.php');
       include($path);
    @endphp
</div>
@endsection
```

Now I have an issue:

** Issue 1 **

I have this kind of code in the old php files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">
```

but I also have scripts in my template (which contains the navbar and footer). Then of course I get this error

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <style>, as they will not be parsed.
```

** Issue 2 **

```
    $.post("./myview.php", "mode=activateForm&id1=<?=$id1?>&id2=<?=$_GET["id2"]?>", function() {

MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

The new issue is this, and I don't get why...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show your file structure?

Answer (score 2):

When you use @include in blade template it will look for the file inside of `resource/views` directory.
so use it like `@include('posts/index')`.

where it will look for index.php inside of `views/posts/` directory.

**Do not use .php inside @include.**

```
@extends('template')

@section('contenu')
<div id="app">

@include("yourDirectory/oldfile");

</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [public path helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-public-path).

Put the files in your public folder and use `public_path('filename.php');` in your include statement.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it works. i now have to deal with two new issues though: how to include the public repo in addition to the file?